# Is HMM of Volatility any different from a simple filter?

Tags: markov-switching

I have constructed a simple HMM ([Hidden Markov Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model)) with 2 states on the Vol (stdev) of a time series of currency returns.

The state vector I produce looks reasonable, in the sense that it appears to have identified periods of high or low vol.

However, I appear to be able to generate a very similar state vector just by applying a simple rule like:

```
if (Vol) > x then 1 else 0.
```

Is there any advantage/difference to using a HMM?

Comment: Maybe that in the HMM case you let the data decide the best set of regimes for you?

Comment: But maybe HMM just splits states in middle of range? if vol goes from 5% to 15% perhaps it just says if Vol > 10% then 1 else 0.     If this is case why bother why more complicated HMM?

Comment: According to my experience with `RHmm` package, it usually does only when the two states have got the same st. dev. As instance, try that with the VIX index: you will get the "panic" state quite above 24 but with a huge variance (which explains the over 40 spikes). If you splitted in the middle range, you'd get different values.

Comment: OK I see. So, the informational value of this simple HMM is not very different to my simple rule. BUT the fact I have not picked(optimised it) is useful right?

Comment: It can be a suitable way to test your assumptions, or to make an algorithm to understand what you mean when you want it to search for different regimes. Let you want your algorithm to look for all the commodities whose volatility is in the "panic" state: how is it supposed you to input in the number-cruncher each single volatility regime-couple of underlyings that maybe you don't even know? Instead, create a function that takes returns as inputs, estimate their volatility, perform an HMM and returns the actual state. Then apply it all over your database.

Comment: You do not mention how you construct your volatility variable (perhaps a rolling window). The regime-switching model can provide a conditional volatilities, which happens to be better than a rolling window volatility. You can also use the model for prediction, e.g., what will the volatility be over the next 3 months given what regime I'm in today.

Comment: [Cross-posted to NP](http://www.nuclearphynance.com/Show%20Post.aspx?PostIDKey=168314).

Comment: @user2675052: Is there anything else we could do for you? It is good practice here to upvote and accept the given answers if they satisfy you - Thank you :-)

Answer (score 10):

Have a look at the following paper:
[Regime Shifts: Implications for Dynamic Strategies by Kritzman, Page and Turkington](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2066848)

From the paper (p. 25):

> But why go through all the trouble? When dealing with regime shifts,
>   we expect Markov-switching models to perform better than simple data
>   partitions based on thresholds. For example, in Figure 1, if we had
>   simply classified the observations that were in the highest quartile
>   as being associated with Regime 2 (the high-mean regime), we would
>   have misidentified the actual regime 40 times out of 200 observations.
>   In contrast, a well calibrated Markov-switching model would have
>   misidentified the actual regime only three times. Arbitrary thresholds
>   give false signals because they fail to capture the persistence in
>   regimes as well as changing volatilities

**EDIT**
There doesn't seem to be a free version available any more. If you find one, please let me know: I will then update the link.

Comment: @user2675052: Thank you, I would appreciate if you could upvote and accept my answer then :-)

Comment: @vonjd Link appears to be broken.

Answer (score 1):

HMM allows to get transition matrix that provides additional information itself about probabilities of switching.

As HMM looks on complete state path it allows to identify, for example, short periods of low volatility in high volatility regime that were not a result of regime switching. If we apply some simple rule we have a larger number of switches and thus have biased transition matrix. If the results of this analysis are used in some forecasting or simulations, error in transition matrix would be crucial.